# Using Remastersys to build Ubuntu INstall CD

Tags: ubuntu

I am new to ubuntu . Someone refer me to this if i want to make a installable copy of Ubuntu from already installed Ubuntu.

http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/ubuntu.html

IS this software doing what i want

Answer (score 1):

Reconstructor is a Live CD creator for Ubuntu Linux.

It uses the Ubuntu Linux Live CD as a base, and then allows customization of boot screens (usplash), gnome settings, and software (you can also use the chroot environment to make other changes before creating the live cd).

Reconstructor does not create separate distros. It keeps the solid Ubuntu foundation, and just allows for customization. For example, create a custom Live CD with blender, inkscape, etc. included for a friend in graphics, or simply use reconstructor to re-brand your environment (wallpaper, fonts).

Reconstructor is written in python and is licensed under the GNU General Public License (GPL)

https://www.reconstructor.org/wiki/reconstructor/

Comment: I have seen the option called  "dist" , what does that option do

Comment: i have left blank!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Dist - makes a distributable system without your /home/. the other option makes a full duplicate

Comment: so it means can i install that copy on new system like insert cd on boot

Comment: yes you can, as long as everything went well